# Fancybox doesn't work with jQuery v3.0.0 & fancy v2.1.5

Tags: c#, jquery, fancybox

I am using fancyBox with jQuery v3.0.0. for open fancy box at ajax call.

HTML

```
<a href='/CandidateNote/UDFAndCandidateNote?candidateId=10' class='fancybox fancybox.ajax' title='Notes'>Add Note</a>
```

C# function

```
[UserAuthorize]
public ActionResult UDFAndCandidateNote(int candidateId)
{
   var Model ="";
    ---------------------
   return Content(this.RenderPartialViewToString("Editor.cshtml", Model));
}
```

Partial view CSHTML

```
@{ 
    var i = 0;
    Layout = null;
    Model.IsAjax = true;
}
<div style="width:600px;min-height:250px">
    <div class="fontPadding" style="padding-left: 15px;">
        <span id="noteHead" class="selectedHead">NOTES</span>&nbsp;/&nbsp;
        <span id="udfHead" class="unSelectedHead">USER DEFINED FIELDS</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

It does not open the fancyBox. It redirect to a page with the action name at controller for jquery V3.0.0 with fancy v2.1.5.

**NOTE**
 If I use the jquery v1.8.3 it works fine.

Is there any problem with jquery version?

Comment: have you tried using the migrate plugin? https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate#migrate-older-jquery-code-to-jquery-30

Comment: I try that, but still not working.